# Cannot screen mirror youtube to TV

Tags: youtube, smart-tv

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 with Android 4.4.2 and a Samsung UE48H6270SS.

I can screen mirror my Music and also Media using the [Samsung Smart View App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.smartviewad) but I can't do it with YouTube. There is an option in the YouTube-settings to "pair" a device with a TV, but that requires the TV to install the YouTube-App on the TV which I don't want to install. (Or anything else related to SmartTV). Is there any alternative to the YouTube app or another solution?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no alternative to the YouTube app. However do you expect your TV to decode the video by YouTube. Also: Isn't the YouTube app preinstalled on Samsung Smart TVs? I have one and it came with some preinstalled apps, that are working like a charm.